# How to display variable in for loop in PL/SQL sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

How do we display variable within For Loop?

For ex

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Starting');

   FOR r IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner in ('ABC','CDE')) 
   loop
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('owner');  
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name||' to XXXX';
   end loop;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Ending');
END;
```

I am getting below outputs printed

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Starting
Ending
```

The one within the loop isn't printed

Any changes to be done here?

Comment: it could be that the select statement does not return any value, what is the query results?

Comment: #CuriousProgrammer please correct your answer by removing the quote it should be DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(R.owner); but if it's not printing anything at all that means that the select statement does not return any rows, what is the result of the query?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('R.owner'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(R.owner); 
Both doesn't work
I need to see if it is iterating through both owners

Comment: it seems that this query SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner in ('ABC','CDE') does not return any results, that is why it does not going into the loop statement, check the query results.

Comment: #TheName the individual query works and owner does exists it is only when I put it in For Loop and try to fetch variable value it isn't printing the owner name.It fails to print even if I put just one owner in select query

Comment: Run it in debug mode and see if it goes into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if this fails then it means that this    `SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner in ('ABC','CDE')` does not return anything and that is why its not going into the loop statement

```
 set serveroutput on;
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Starting');
       FOR R IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner in ('ABC','CDE')) 
       loop
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r.owner);  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||R.owner||'.'||R.table_name||' to XXXX';
       end loop;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Ending');
    END;
```

Comment: It does exist TheName.If I run the query standalone it fetches result